# Devise Ruby Gem NameError when installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I was trying to install the Ruby Gem Devise and I stupidly overlooked a step. I included the gem in my gemfile then ran the bundle install on the prompt. Then I forgot to run the generator `rails generate devise:install`.

Then when I went to generate my User model it came up with the following error `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in`const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)`

I've tried uninstalling the gem and removing anything that refers to `Users` and reinstalling the gem but it keeps coming up with the same error.

I'm hoping someone can maybe shine a bit of light on this issue

Comment: do you mind sharing the command you wrote in to the terminal when trying to generate your model?

Comment: sure it was 'rails g model User

Comment: How about taking the gem out of your gem file and running `bundle`.  Don't add the devise gem back and run the `rails g model User` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the issue. When you run the bundle install command, it automatically configures the routes folder, so I've removed any reference to devise and it's worked now

Comment: I should really learn to read all the documentation first lol